# Magento 2 Multi Language Force language

Tags: magento, magento2, multilingual

We have a multi language store beststore.ae running on Magento 2.3.5p2

We have English Language and Arabic Language for the store and the default language is English

Is their a way to set up a link to access directly the Arabic store like (/?language=ar), and we also need to set it up with all the links to have a language option embedded in the url link

do magento 2 support this ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes magento 2 does support this , checking your website the Arabic store can be accessed directly on https://beststore.ae/ar/ .

If this is not the answer you're looking for maybe you can add more details to the question

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in CLI in your Magento 2 Root Installation folder:

```
php bin/magento config:set web/url/use_store 1
```

Then run in CLI:

```
php bin/magento c:f config full_page
```

Now, you should see the 'website_code' of each Website Store Front in the URL.